# Getting Alerts to stop a Link

Tags: javascript

How do I use a alert to stop a link from going to the page? I've been trying to figure it out but it's sending me to the link anyways

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Do Not Click</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        </head>
        <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function confirm_alert(node) {

            return confirm("STOP CLICKING THE LINK");   
        }

        </script>
        <a href="www.yahoo.com" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);">Don't click link</a>



        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the param `event` and execute the function `.preventDefault()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Do Not Click</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_alert(node, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return confirm("STOP CLICKING THE LINK");
    }
  </script>
  <a href="www.yahoo.com" onclick="return confirm_alert(this, event);">Don't click link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**A better approach is binding the event click:**

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', confirm_alert);

function confirm_alert(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return confirm("STOP CLICKING THE LINK");
}
```

```html
<a href="www.yahoo.com">Don't click link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return false from the confirm_alert function.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Do Not Click</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        </head>
        <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function confirm_alert(node) {

            confirm("STOP CLICKING THE LINK");  
            return false;
        }

        </script>
        <a href="www.yahoo.com" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);">Don't click link</a>



        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the redirect in the js function. Put a check in it for showing the alert or for going to the url.

Something like this:
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

Not sure tho. Not tested it.